# Compatibility with Joomla 4

Tags: joomla

I was just going to upgrade to the latest version of Joomla, but it's a major upgrade (version 4), so I thought I would check that CiviCRM is compatible. Can anyone confirm?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several open issues for Joomla 4 listed here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/-/issues

If you are in a position to help investigate or fix those, go ahead with 4 - but the easier option for now is Joomla 3.

Comment: Thank you. It looks quite a daunting task, but I will have a look when I get a moment.